# Is there a program that can batch rename/replace file names?

Tags: file-management, batch

I have a whole list of files that I need to update, however the new files all have _judge after them. I've tried using some program called Renamer but every time I remove the _judge in that program it give an error that the file already exists.

So for example I want to do

common_parts_judge > common_parts

However since common_parts already exists it won't replace it and just give an error instead.

Does anyone know a piece of software that will replace renamed duplicates?